# Reading/writing data to encrypted custom file type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'd like to create a custom file type, say, .cstm, and be able to create .cstm files on the mac, and read them on the iPhone.

I want the .cstm file to contain XML data. Currently I've got the mac app to successfully make .xml files and the iPhone app to successfully read .xml files, but I'd like to create a proprietary custom file type.

How would I go about doing this? I know how to allow the iPhone app to open a custom file type, but that's as far as I know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special per se. You can just save and load to the URL with the ctsm extension. To support your app automatically launching as an editor of that extension in OSX, you will want to add an entry to your Info.plist file `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array entry declaring your app as an editor of that extension

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107

Comment: No. You have full control over file serialization/deserialization. For information on the built in cryptography of OSX and iOS, check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html